# Convergence of quotient of a polynomial and exponential

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let, $ P(x)$ be a real polynomial such that $P(x) \to \infty$ as $ x\to \infty$ and $ f(x)$ be a real smooth function such that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $ x\to \infty$. Can we say, $ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{P(x)}{e^{f(x)}}= 0? $

I am unable to find any counterexamples. I tried to prove the statement using L'Hospital rule, but couldn't prove it. Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:  As mentioned in the comment, when $ f(x)= \log x$ and $P(x)= x^2$, we get a counterexample. My question is how to prove or disprove the statement when $ f(x)= \frac{x}{ \log x}$?

Comment: No, because $f$ can grow arbitrarily slow. For example $P(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) = \ln(x)$.

Comment: Yeah, but in particular I was thinking f(x)= x/lnx type function. Sorry. Let me mention that in the question.

Comment: $x/\ln(x)$ grows faster than $x^{1/2}$, and $\exp$ grows faster than any polynomial. That is sufficient to prove your conjecture.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But if we take $ f(x)= \frac{x}{\log (Mx^2)}$ , where M is a fixed positive integer, does the conjecture still hold?

Comment: $\log(M x^2) = \log(M) + 2 \log(x)$, so that does not really make a difference.

Comment: Thank you, It is clear now.